# How to make an excel Filter working in python

Tags: python, excel, filter

In order to get values from an excel file I'm using openpyxl and the following code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('excelname.xlsx')
sheet = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('sheet')
print ('sheet', sheet)
mylist_O = []
for col in sheet['O']:
     mylist_O.append(col.value)
```

this basically will point at the sheet name I'm interested in, and copy the whole column 'O' into a list.
Now I've made an attempt in excel, making a filter on the column 'O' on a specific word. Doing so the number of elements shown in the column are reduced. Than I've saved the excel an closed it.
When I run again the code above I see that the number of elements of mylist_O are unchanged...so basically the code doesn't see the filter.
Is there a command to append in the mylist_O only the elements which are shown in excel avoinding so a filter in python as could  be:

```
for col in sheet['O']:
    if col.find(word)!=-1:
        mylist_O.append(col.value)
```

where word is the "excel" filter.

Comment: Does the [openpyxl doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) answer your question?

Comment: eh no this is not what I was looking for.  according to the doc: "It’s possible to filter single range of values in a worksheet by adding an autofilter. " I don't want to add a filter using opepyxl but viceversa I want to get the values which are already fildered using the excel function.